# Cloud Code and Parse

Tags: parse-platform

Beginning with Cloud Code and Parse. Using this.

Do I need to remove all Parse projects in order to begin creating a new one? How do I do this? I get the following error:

"Would you like to create a new app, or add Cloud Code to an existing app? Type "(n)ew" or "(e)xisting": e 1: Test Select an App to add to config: 2 Detected that you are already inside a Parse project. Please refrain from creating a Parse project inside another Parse project."

I have deleted my all application from the account and tried again but still facing the same problem.

After running parse new command again ,asked me for the credentials and name of the new application but after that got the same error.

Comment: Got one but temporary. Have to do ls-la then fire  command rm .parse.local and rm .parse.project .After that I can create new or work on existing project.

Comment: @kumarijyoti Thanks. Your comment here helped. :)